# ITextSharp, Assigning a font to List within a cell?

Tags: itext

Is there a way to assign a font to a list that is added to table cell in ITextsharp. I'm sure it must be straightforward but I'm missing it.

```
Dim tblSignature As New PdfPTable(1)
        tblSignature.WidthPercentage = 90.0F

        Dim _baseFont As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)

        Dim _bFont As New Font(_baseFont, 4, Font.ITALIC, Color.RED)

        Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(TheItem.Value, _bFont))

        TheParagraph.Font = _bFont


        Dim list As New List(list.UNORDERED, 25.0F)
        list.SetListSymbol("[  ]")


        If ListItems.Count > 0 Then
            For Each ListItem In .ListItems
                //I have tried adding as chunk/phrase and applying font but no joy
                //Item not added to cell
                //list.Add(New Chunk(ListItem, _bFont))

                list.Add(ListItem)
            Next

            list.IndentationLeft = 5.0F

            cell.AddElement(list)
        End If

        cell.Colspan = 6
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        cell.PaddingBottom = 5.0F
        cell.PaddingLeft = 5.0F
        cell.PaddingRight = 5.0F

        '' add to doc
        tblSignature.AddCell(cell)

        TheParagraph.Add(tblSignature)
```

Does anyone know How I'd change this so that the list/cell has the specific font I've set at the top.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `iTextSharp.text.ListItem` object has an `iTextSharp.text.Font` property you can set.

Comment: Bloody hell, I was applying a string directly to the list rather than using a ListItem, thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Please note that declarations such as  new PdfPCell or new Phrase will not work with iTextSharp.text.List's add method.But both of them fairly work with PdfPTable.
I used iTextSharp.text.List for one of my software's pdf print out in  the following ways.I hope this may be useful to you also.

This is a program which is used in one of my software developed with vb.net(visual studio 2010 and windows 7 platform) and iTextSharp latest version.
 for pdf print out.It demonstrates how we can manupulate iTextSharp.text.List's font properties.

```
 Dim doc1 As New Document()

        Dim pathpdf As String = "C:/temp"

        'path = ServerMapPath("PDFs");
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, New FileStream(pathpdf + "/Doc1.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        ' Now to begin actually working with the document, open it, , add a new list,and, then close it:

        doc1.Open()


Dim fnt1 As Font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)


Dim fnt2 As Font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 14, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD)


Dim fnt3 As Font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)


Dim lst3 As New iTextSharp.text.List()


lst3.SetListSymbol("")


'add a list item in bold letters.

Dim m_DataHeadOnly As String

m_DataHeadOnly = "This is the itextsharp font setting with list"

lst3.Add(New iTextSharp.text.ListItem(m_DataHeadOnly, fnt2))


doc1.add(lst3)

doc1.close()
```